# Unix - alter IP field an csv and output new file

Tags: linux, file, csv, unix, calc

Hoping for some input on this, as I'm struggling. I have a csv that contains an IP mask in which I want to get the network IP and broadcast IP. 
So for instance I want the input field 1.0.0.0/24 to output 2 new field that contain the vaules: 1.0.0.0 in one and 1.0.0.255 in the other.
I have code to do this.

For broadcast:

```
for i in $(cat geoip.csv);do bcaddr=$(ipcalc -n -b $i);echo 
${bcaddr#BROADCAST=};done
```

And for network:

```
for i in $(cat geoip.csv);do bcaddr=$(ipcalc -n -4 $i);echo 
${bcaddr#BROADCAST=};done
```

Where do I go from here? How do I go about appending these 2 new fields to a new output file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

see if this works on RHEL 5.x... do you want the output in csv with comma separator?
`for i in $(cat csip.csv); do echo "$i $(ipcalc -n -b $i | grep -E "Address|Broadcast" | awk {'print ","$2'} | tr '\n' ' ')" ; done > new.csv`

For your version of ipcalc, please try this:
`for i in $(cat csip.csv); do echo "$i $(ipcalc -n -b $i | grep -E "NETWORK|BROADCAST" | awk -F= {'print ","$2'} | tr '\n' ' ')" ; done > new.csv`

Comment: Yes, I'd like the output with a comma separator. I tried your suggestion. It doesn't add the new needed fields, it just prints what is already in the csv.

Comment: answer updated, let me know how it goes.  If it doesn't work, can I see your output of `ipcalc -n -b 1.0.0.0/24`?

Comment: Hello, it didn't work. Same data from the source but added blank rows between each line of data. I posted screenshots [here](https://imgur.com/a/TMzkUqQ)

Comment: Got the screenshot, see my updated answer, the 2nd one that grep for NETWORK or BROADCAST

Answer (score 0):

Why not using awk?

If you are using Linux (Not Unix):

```
for i in $(cat geoip.csv);do bcaddr=$(ipcalc -n -b  $i); echo $bcaddr | egrep -o '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+' ; done > ip.txt
```

**Output:**

```
1.0.0.255
1.0.0.0
```

If you want the output in a single line:

```
for i in $(cat geoip.csv);do bcaddr=$(ipcalc -n -b  $i); echo $bcaddr | egrep -o '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+' ORS=' ' ; done}' > ip.txt
```

**Output:**

```
1.0.0.255 1.0.0.0
```

Comment: Both of those examples give me the message: "ipcalc: netmask or prefix expected". Also, I want the the output to be the broadcast and network IP (new fields) to be in a new .csv file that contains the other fields from the original file.

Comment: Red Hat Ent 5.10

Comment: Editing my answer

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the results appear on the screen, not a text file.

Comment: Of course, you have to pipe them with redirects `> file`

Comment: But how do I get the results appended to the existing file - in a new file together?

Comment: For the same file, you need `sed`. Redirect for a new file.